# Why i can't access Data user in Session when in checkout page

Tags: php

I want to ask, what's wrong with the code that I made? I want to access the data of the user who is currently logged into the session so that it appears automatically filling out the checkout form. So users do not need to bother anymore to input data manually.

[my checkout page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3rR3.png)

I made it in native PHP, **How to solve this?** Thank you

**This my checkout page COde**

```
<div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
                    <h4 class="mb-3">Detail Pembayaran</h4>
                    <form method="post" action="akun.php?c_id=<?php echo $id_member; ?>" name="checkout" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                        <?php
                           if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                               $id_member = $_SESSION['user'];
                               $get_member = "SELECT * FROM tbluser where id_member = '$id_member'";
                               $run_member = mysqli_query($con,$get_member);
                               if ($row_member = mysqli_num_rows($run_member)>0) {
                                   $m_nama = $row_member['nama_member'];
                                   $m_username = $row_member['username_member'];
                                   $m_email = $row_member['email_member'];
                                   $m_alamat = $row_member['alamat_member'];

                               }
                           }
                         ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                <label >Nama Lengkap</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="m_nama" value="<?php echo $m_nama ?>"
                                    disabled >
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Nama Harus Valid.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="m_username" value="<?php echo $m_username ?>" disabled>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                                    username harus diisi.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label>Email <span class="text-muted"></span></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $m_email ?>" disabled>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Email harus diisi.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="address">Alamat</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $m_alamat ?>" disabled>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Alamat Harus diisi.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="mb-4">

                        <h4 class="mb-3">Pembayaran</h4>

                        <div class="d-block my-3">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="cash" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" checked
                                    required>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="cash">Cash</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input id="transfer" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input"
                                    disabled>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="transfer">Transfer (Soon)</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="mb-4">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5" type="submit" name="submit" value="Masukkan Ke
                            Keranjang">
                    </form>
```

**This is my Login page code(session declare)**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
        header("Location: index-member.php");
    }

    include ("functions/functions.php");
    include ("inc/db.php");

    //cEK LOGIN TOMBOL SUDAH DI KLIK ATAU Belum
    if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $get_ip = getIpUser();
        $id_member = "select * from tbluser where id_member = '$get_ip'";
        $username_member = $_POST["m_username"];
        $password_member = $_POST["m_password"];


        $cek_username = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE username_member = '$username_member'");

        // Cek Username ada sama atau tidak
        if ( mysqli_num_rows($cek_username) === 1) {
            //CEK PASSWORD
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cek_username);
            if( password_verify($password_member, $row["password_member"]) ) {
                //Set Session
                $_SESSION["login"] = true;
                $_SESSION["user"] = $username_member;

                header("Location: index-member.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
        $error = true;
    }
 ?>

 <?php
```

Comment: what answer you got? Did you debug?

Answer (score -1):

You store the value of `$_POST['m_username']` in `$_SESSION['user']`, but then query for `id_member = $_SESSION['user']`...

```
$get_ip = getIpUser();
$id_member = "select * from tbluser where id_member = '$get_ip'";
$username_member = $_POST["m_username"];
...

$_SESSION["user"] = $username_member;
```

and

```
$id_member = $_SESSION['user'];
$get_member = "SELECT * FROM tbluser where id_member = '$id_member'";
```

Comment: but still show error
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: m_nama in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\hatex\checkout.php</b> on line <b>226</b><br />

Comment: but how? what should i fix and how? i don't get it. I'm new learn PHP. and I follow tutorial and try to modify. and I get stuck here.

could you please help me? what should I change and where? or maybe you have an example?

Thank you

Comment: I listed the problems... you search with different values, don't you see that?